# Requiring constants within jest.mock

Tags: jestjs

I have a module that exports a function and a constant. I am trying to just require and read this while doing a `jest.mock` but constants are all undefined.

`/useEvalNames.js`

```
import { doAnotherThing } from '/doAnotherThing';

export const NAMES = ['Foo', 'Bar'];

export default function useEvalNames() {
   
}
```

I want to test `useEvalNames` but I need to do some mocking, and this is where I run into the problem, `NAMES` is `undefined`:

`/__tests__/useEvalNames.test.js`

```
describe('#useEvalNames', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });

  it('works', () => {
    jest.mock('./doAnotherThing', () => {
      const withRequireActual = jest.requireActual('../useEvalNames');

      console.log('withRequireActual.NAMES:', withRequireActual.NAMES); // prints undefined

      const withRequire = require('../useEvalNames');

      console.log('withRequire.NAMES:', withRequire.NAMES); // prints undefined

      return {}
    });

    const { NAMES, useEvalNames } = require('../useEvalNames');
    console.log('NAMES:', NAMES); // this prints fine ['Foo', 'Bar']
  });
});
```

The problem is seen above where I say "prints undefined". This is real weird. If I convert `const NAMES = []` to a function `function NAMES() { return [] }` then it doesn't print undefined.

Does anyone know why this is? Anyway to import those constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest.requireActual('../useEvalNames')` evaluates `useEvalNames`, which is evaluated in mocked `doAnotherThing`, which is evaluated in `useEvalNames`. This is circular dependency. CommonJS modules don't handle circular dependencies.

If original module that `jest.requireActual('../useEvalNames')` returns is being used, it should be imported outside `jest.mock` to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Oh thank you, I will test this out tomorrow.